# extract particular value from a string

Tags: php

Suppose I have a variable that holds a web address as follows:

```
$url="http://www.example.com/login?u=17474&l=6277";
```

now I send the above url to a function

```
$out= myFunc($url);
```

Now what I want is that the function should return only the part of url before the ? i.e, if the above url is passed to the function it should return http://example.com/login also if a relative url is passed like /login.php?u=26337&g=777 it should return only /login.php.

also I want to get the values in the url and set cookies for in the above I want the value inside u and set the cookie with the value.

```
  function myFunc($url){
      $pass= substr($url,0,strpos($url,'?'));
   $u = ;//the value in; 
   setcookie('user',$u);
return $pass;
 }
```

How can I do this??

Comment: thats a vry big code can't copy that

Comment: Then answers will have the same problem, their code will not be posted!? Come on :-) See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where is $url coming from?

Comment: If the string is an URL then check the documentation of [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). Otherwise, for general strings, read about [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) PHP functions. Also [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) can be used for such things, to some extent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function must return the substring before "?":

```
function myFunc($url){
    return substr($url,0,strpos($url,'?'));
}
$url="http://www.example.com/login?u=17474&l=6277";
echo myFunc($url);// http://www.example.com/login
```

to convert the get string to array, use parse_str() function:

```
function get_values($url){
    parse_str(substr($url,strpos($url,'?')+1),$array);
    return $array;
}
$values = get_values($url);
print_r($values);//Array ( [u] => 17474 [l] => 6277 )
```

To access `u`:

```
$u = $values['u'];
setcookie('user',$u);
```

remember to setcookie before any output to the browser!

Comment: that would do but I need the values too. see I have edited the ques

Answer (score 1):

[parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url) may help you. Just use it like:

```
$url="http://www.example.com/login?u=17474&l=6277";
$url_segments = parse_url($url);

echo $url_segments['path'];
```

Comment: do you want to  get script file name?